# Does 'cache: false' PREVENT caching, or UNIQUE-IFY the request to bypass cached?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, backbone.js

If I make multiple requests for a resource via ajax calls with 'cache: false', does this *prevent* the browser from caching each response using the request header (or some other way), or does it *bypass* the previously cached responses because the resource url is made unique due to the _=date param and thus never matches anything in the cache?

As a reference, here is the jquery documentation on the ajax's cache property: '*If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters.*'

So does it really 'force requested pages not to be cached'? Or does it simply imitate that effect by appending the date - with the affect that no two requests are ever the same and so a fresh request made (but all the while the poor browser has a whole bunch of cached but never used responses)?

(If I am so miss understanding the way caching works please feel free to school me!! (I'm assuming its basically a key value type of system with the key being the request information, and the value being the response for that request.))

Comment: `Or does it simply imitate` yes.

Answer (score 0):

yes, if you set `cache: false`, then it just append _={timestamp} after url + params.

from jquery [src](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js):

```
cacheURL = s.url;

    // More options handling for requests with no content
    if ( !s.hasContent ) {

        // If data is available, append data to url
        if ( s.data ) {
            cacheURL = ( s.url += ( rquery.test( cacheURL ) ? "&" : "?" ) + s.data );
            // #9682: remove data so that it's not used in an eventual retry
            delete s.data;
        }

        // Add anti-cache in url if needed
        if ( s.cache === false ) {
            s.url = rts.test( cacheURL ) ?

                // If there is already a '_' parameter, set its value
                cacheURL.replace( rts, "$1_=" + nonce++ ) :

                // Otherwise add one to the end
                cacheURL + ( rquery.test( cacheURL ) ? "&" : "?" ) + "_=" + nonce++;
        }
    }
```